# how can i add totalresults to my response ? here is my code . it returns the results as intended but i want to get total result number

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, clean-architecture

```cs
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetPagedReponseAsync(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{            
    var result = await _dbContext
    .Set<T>()
    .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
    return result;
}
```

Result contains the paginated datas as intended but how can I return total number of results with the response data?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a specific response object containing your items + additional data (like items count). Make a database request for items count + items request itself. For example:

```
public class PagedResponse<T>
{
    public PagedResponse(IReadOnlyCollection<T> items, int count)
    {
        Items = items;
        TotalCount = count;
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<T> Items { get; }
    public int TotalCount { get; }
}

public async Task<PagedResponse<T>> GetPagedReponseAsync<T>(int pageNumber, int pageSize) where T : class
{
    var count = await _dbContext.Set<T>().CountAsync();
            
    var result = await _dbContext
    .Set<T>()
    .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();

    return new PagedResponse(result, count);
}
```